# How to get tags from RDS DBInstance

Tags: java, api, tags, rds

I have a problem when I try to get Tags from RDS DBInstances on java.

```
AmazonRDS rds = new AmazonRDSClient(credentialsProvider);
ListTagsForResourceRequest request = new ListTagsForResourceRequest();
ListTagsForResourceResult resultedTags = rds.listTagsForResource(request);

Status Code: 500, AWS Service: AmazonRDS, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: InternalFailure, AWS Error Message: An internal error has occurred. Please try your query again at a later time.
Stack Trace:
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:614)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:312)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:165)
at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:1992)
at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.listTagsForResource(AmazonRDSClient.java:746)
at com.vqs.AwsConsoleApp.getRDSInstances(AwsConsoleApp.java:98)
at com.vqs.AwsConsoleApp.main(AwsConsoleApp.java:73)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Amazon RDS API reference, it looks like the `ResourceName` parameter on the request is required:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ListTagsForResource.html

Try setting that request parameter with one of your RDS DB instance IDs and you should get a good response back.

I'm not sure why you didn't get a more helpful error message back from the service.  I'll pass that info along to the RDS team.

Hope that helps!